# Why this code remove product of state in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have simple code

```
export default function asideReducer(state = initialState, action) {
  let cart = state.cart
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      let itemInCart = cart.find(item => item.product._id == action.payload.product._id)
      if(itemInCart)
      {
        let newQuantity = itemInCart.quantity;
        newQuantity++;
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [{...itemInCart, quantity: newQuantity}]
        }
      } else{
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
        }
      }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I click to elements and if item NOT find in state cart i simple add to state cart, but if Item is in cart, i add quantity. But if i add some products , after 2-3 click products remove from state. But don't exists operation with remove products? I thinks maybe it's not correct worked.

```
return {
          ...state,
          cart: [{...itemInCart, quantity: newQuantity}]
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is actually erasing all the other items in the cart:

```
cart: [{...itemInCart, quantity: newQuantity}]
```

Instead, consider mapping over the cart and only replacing the quantity for the matching item:

```
cart: state.cart.map(item => {
  return item !== itemInCart
    ? item
    : { ...itemInCart, quantity: newQuantity }
})
```